# Как создать функцию в jquery и вызвать ее при клике?

Tags: jquery, функции

Привет всем. У меня есть функция

```
$(document).ready(function($){

function del_img(img){ 
alert();
}

});
```

пытаюсь ее вызвать  `<span onclick="del_img('test');">x</span>`  , но не вызывается .Почему ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Это поможет другим пользователям сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите так:

```
<span data-text="test">Click me</span>

$(function() {
    $('span').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).data("text");
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: у меня в span должен быть аргумент  ..Как реализовать ?

Comment: добавил исправления

Comment: Благодарю.......